# How can I include all my html files in my base.html file in django?

Tags: html, django, templates, django-templates, jinja2

I have a couple of html files in my django project including a base.html file, navbar.html, footer.html, etc. I have included the navbar and footer files in the base file and extended the base file to a home.html file which happens to be my main page. I recently created a courses.html file and would like this page to also be in the main page. I understand I can include it like I did with navbar and footer, but that would mean the courses.html file will be shown everywhere the base file has been extended to, and I don't want this. How can I do this?

Comment: Your question are too indirect. You should always bring some code you already use. Otherwise you expect us to do more work put in answers than you put in your question.

Answer (score 0):

If you include `courses.html` only in `home.html` then it will be seen only in view that `home.html` is a template in.

Anything you include in `base.html` will be seen at every page which uses `{% extends 'base.html' %}`.